# Yocto: Create a New Directory in etcdir

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I am new to Yocto,
I want to create a directory in `/etc` and copy my server certificates into that directory. I tried doing below, But it is not creating any directory in `/etc`, however I am not getting any compilation error:

```
DESCRIPTION = "OC sample service"

SUMMARY = "Install and start a systemd service and copy server certificates"

LICENSE = "MIT"

SRC_URI = "file://service.tar.gz"

inherit systemd

S = "${WORKDIR}/service"

SYSTEMD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "sample.service"
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "enable"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "installed-vs-shipped"

do_configure() {
        :
}

do_compile() {
        :
}

do_install() {

        install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system

        install -m 0755 ${S}/sample.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system

        mkdir -p ${D}${etcdir}/oc_certs

        install -m 0755 ${S}/certs/* ${D}${etcdir}/oc_certs

}

FILES_${PN} = "${systemd_unitdir}/system
```

"

[image: service.tar.gz contains following]

Now the problem is, sample.service is successfully being placed to the location but `/etc/oc_certs` is not being created.

Comment: 'Not working' does not explain what is not working exactly. If you get an error message, do provide that. If the snippet is not executed, then provide the full recipe you are working on, so we can see why is it not executed. 

Generally, use the following pattern when asking questions:
a) what do you expect to happen, *specifically*
b) what is actually happening, *specifically*

Comment: Hi @AlexanderKanavin, Thanks for the quick comment, I have updated my question.

Comment: FILES seems still to be missing the directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to LetoThe2nd's answer: the `${etcdir}` variable is usually empty. If you want a variable for `/etc`, it is `${sysconfdir}`. So your files are probably installed to root directory.

Check output of `bitbake -e <your_recipe>` and try to find `etcdir` to verify.

Also drop `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "installed-vs-shipped"` which hides the error your are trying to find (you will see what is installed where but not shipped).

BTW LetoThe2nd's answer is also needed, because you are overwriting (instead of appending `FILES_${PN}`, otherwise it wouldn't be needed. The `${sysconfdir}` is already part of `FILES_${PN}`.

Answer (score 3):

"Not working" is a rather bad error description, but the most probable issue is that it does not get included in the image. This is because bitbakes packaging mechanisms do not know about that directory, so add it with:

```
FILES_${PN} += "${etcdir}/oc_certs"
```

If you need further assistance, please extend your question with a precise error description, respectively the corresponding log.

Comment: Hi LetoThe2nd, Thanks for the responce,
I added  FILES_${PN} += "${etcdir}/oc_certs", but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a / after ${D}. To create a directory say **mydir** in your /etc folder, just add the following code in the do_install() of your recipe.

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/etc/mydir
 }
```

Comment: Well, the `${sysconfdir}` contains `/etc`, so in that particular question the slash isn't needed. But it is true that `${D}` doesn't contain the trailing slash.